# FDT code assist broken on project uploaded to subversion repository

Tags: svn, actionscript, fdt

I recently started working in FDT (used to work with FlashDevelop) and I encountered a very strange problem.

When I make a new project everything is fine, I can code without problem in as3 and also using the flixel engine is no problem.

However, as soon as I checkout a project from subversion, the code assist breaks.
The code still works, the program executes without errors.

But instead of giving me a few option when I type "FlxG." it just gives me a lot of options regarding 'metadata'.

I have looked at a lot of places but I can not find the answer anywhere.

I really hope there is someone out here who can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Dennis

Comment: Do you have any errors at all anywhere? Checking out a project from SVN itself will not cause a problem. Can you provide a screenshot? Is the project you checked out an FDT project? Do you have all of the FDT icons in your project? It's likely that what you checked out was a generic project and does not have the FDT nature with it.

Comment: I made 2 screenshots. 
the one without the arrow is the one I checked out, and the one with the arrow is THE SAME code, but in a locally made project.
http://imageshack.us/g/571/nothinge.png/
It sounds really logical that it would be a generic project, do you know how I can change or fix that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your source code (your .AS file) is not in a 'source folder'. Notice how source folders are blue and the other folders are white? FDT only provides editor features, such as autocomplete & quick fixes, to .AS and .MXML files which are in source folders.

To get editor features for these files, either:

- Place the files in an existing source folder.
- Convert the generic folder into a source folder.
- Create a new source folder and place the files there.

**Video**

[See this video](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/154189/web/stackexchange/source_folders.mov) where I do all three of those.

**Screenshot**

Here is a picture that shows the different folder types:

[image]

Comment: thats it!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! awesome response ;) loved the video! thanks again!